# FEniCS: extracting points from a cell

Tags: c++, fenics

I'd like to loop over all edges of a simplex (in a mesh). To this end: How can I extract the the points from a cell?

This is for the `eval` method of a C++ definition of an `Expression`, i.e.,

```
void eval(Array<double>& v,                                                     
          const Array<double>& x,                                               
          const ufc::cell& c                                                    
         ) const
{
Cell cell(*mesh, c.index);                                                  
// do something with cell?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use an iterator to access the entities connected to a cell, like the edges in your case. Just as you suggest, you first need to create a dolfin::Cell from the ufc::cell. Then do something like this:

```
void eval(Array<double>& v,                                                     
          const Array<double>& x,                                               
          const ufc::cell& c) const
{
  Cell cell(*mesh, c.index);                                                  
  for (EdgeIterator edge(cell); !edge.end(); ++edge)
  {
    // Do something with edge
  }
}
```

For speed, and maybe easier access, you could directly access the edges (entities of dimension 1 as follows):

```
const unsigned int* edge_indices = cell.entities(1);
Edge e0(mesh, edge_indices[0]);
Edge e1(mesh, edge_indices[1]);
Edge e2(mesh, edge_indices[2]);
```

In a similar way, you can access the vertices of the edges (by calling `cell.entities(0)` or `ei.entities(0)`).

Note that for this to work, you need to instantiate the edges of the mesh (they will be created automatically by the iterators). You can do this by

```
mesh.init(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do. Here, I assume that `mesh` is your mesh, `Q` is the function space and that you use the dolfin interface in python.

```
for (i, cell) in enumerate(cells(mesh)):
    print "Global dofs associated with cell %d: " % i
    print Q.dofmap().cell_dofs(i)
    print "The Dof coordinates:"
    print Q.dofmap().tabulate_coordinates(cell)
```

Comment: This is actually in Python, but I guess to define a custom expression on that level, I need to provide the C++ code. I modified the question accordingly.